# How can I force Plotly animation to start by the last frame?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I would like to change the 'default' frame of my animated chart and force it to use the last date as default when the Dash application is rendered. How can I do this?

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

I'm trying some different approaches, like something like it:

```
fig.layout['sliders'][0]['active'] = 11

and

frame = -1
fig = go.Figure(fig.frames[frame].data, fig.frames[frame].layout)
fig
```

but it's not being reflected correctly on the chart.

Could someone give me a direction on how I can I found references about it?

I want to force the graph to start on the last year.

Comment: If the provided suggestion solved your problem, please upvote an mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey vestland, thanks for the advice, I'm not too experienced on StackOverflow dynamic yet. What should I do if my own answer is the correct answer?

Comment: I would do exaclty what you did; give credit to those who have helped you. Especially if their suggestion in any way helped you build *your* perfect solution. I'm not sure if that's the case here, but I would do it like that either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `fig.data` you have the first frame. I found a workaround generating a new figure.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

# New figure
fig2 = go.Figure()

# add last frame traces to fig2
for tr in fig.frames[-1].data:
    fig2.add_trace(tr)

# copy the layout
fig2.layout = fig.layout

#  copy the frames
fig2.frames = fig.frames

# set last frame as the active one
fig2.layout['sliders'][0]['active'] = len(fig.frames) - 1

fig2
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much for your answer bro; It works.

I had built a solution that is similar to yours but with some differences:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

last_frame_num = len(fig.frames) -1

fig.layout['sliders'][0]['active'] = last_frame_num

fig = go.Figure(data=fig['frames'][-1]['data'], frames=fig['frames'], layout=fig.layout)

fig
```

Anyway, I appreciate a lot your attention/support, it's ever great to have more options when implementing something!

Thank you very much;
Best Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: You could skip the last_frame_num and set `data=fig.frames[-1].data` and consider that `len(fig.frames) - 1` is already an `int`.

Comment: Yeah, It's a nice thing I will edit the code; I set this way because of when I tried to implement with -1 it didn't work on the slider active parameter, so I decided to set a variable with this value to be sure that it will ever be the same.

Comment: For me, this doesn't work for setting an arbitrary frame number (like 5 instead of "last_frame_num").  It displays the correct frame then animation begins back at zero.